# Why it is not possible to terminate loop from a signal handler in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, signals

Does anybody can explain why the next script does not work? What is the cause for the `Label not found for "last SOME_BLOCK"` error?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
SOME_BLOCK: {
    alarm 1;
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        last SOME_BLOCK;
    };
    my $count = 0;
    while (1) {
        $count += 1;
        say $count;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exiting a subroutine via `last` or `next` is forbidden according to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) (and generally triggers a warning). This is because it's quite messy - Perl would need to search dynamically up scopes to find the block that you're trying to skip, and call return from various functions (but what return value should be used?). `return` is generally safer.

In the signal handling context, it's extra messy because Perl actually has to pause execution of your script in order to execute the signal handler. So it's now running two separate execution contexts, and the signal handler context cannot affect the control flow of the main context directly, which is why you get that error.

There are two things you can do:

- throw an exception (using `die`) and catch it in the outer block. This is undesirable, as it could interrupt pretty much anything.
- set a global flag defined outside the signal handler e.g. (`$caught_signal = 1`) and check for that in the inner code at a convenient point.

Comment: Throwing `die` is not only not undesireable, it's the normal thing to do. Signals don't interrupt "pretty much anything". Since they are only checked between Perl ops, you won't die in the middle of a system call, library call or Perl op.

Comment: I agree, but it's still not as nice as checking at well-defined points in your code.